# hide/remove url extension in windows servers

Tags: html, .htaccess, iis

I read that .htaccess doesn't work on windows server like godaddy. So to hide or remove extensions like .php and .html on URL, you can accomplish this by creating a web.config file with the following code:

```
<configuration>   
  <system.webServer>   
    <rewrite>          
      <rules>             
        <rule name="RewriteHTML">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">                     
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />                     
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                 
          </conditions>                 <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.html" />             
        </rule>                
      </rules>      
    </rewrite>   
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

I tried to make web.config file and save it where index.php is with that code but nothing happened.. I tested it with the like this

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a  href="attackontitan-3">Attack on Titan Episode 3</a>
  </li>
</ul> with a href of "attackontitan-3"
```

I want url to be http://mysite/watching/attack%20on%20titan/attackontitan-3 not http://mysite/watching/attack%20on%20titan/attackontitan-3.php

Answer (score 0):

Use rewrite to add the extension, like this:

```
<rule name="rewritephp">
       <!--Removes the .aspx extension for all pages.-->
       <match url="(.*)" />
       <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
         <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
     </rule>
```

Or This tutorial does a great job at explaining what you need to do with IIS.

http://atlantawebsites.blogspot.com/2010/06/vanity-urls-with-godaddy-hosting-using.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Rewrite` and `Redirect` rules.  The following will redirect and rewrite `page.php` to just `page`.  If you want to do the same for html, just add those rules.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
         <rules>

            <!-- Remove the existing rules just incase we already defined them -->
            <remove name="RedirectPhpExtensions" />
            <remove name="RewritePhpExtensions" />

            <!-- Add a rule to redirect x.php pages to just x -->
            <rule name="RedirectPhpExtensions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)\.php$" />
               <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>

            <!-- Add a rule to rewrite the x pages to x.php behind the scene -->
            <rule name="RewritePhpExtensions" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
               <match url="(.*)" negate="false" />
               <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
               </conditions>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.php" />
            </rule>

         </rules>
      </rewrite>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Place this web.config in the root directory of your domain.

Then you need to restart the Application Pool on godaddy's site:

> Web Hosting > Manage > IIS Management > Recycle App Pool button